# Linear regression package result vs econometric result mismatch

Tags: r, regression, econometrics, linear

```
x <- c(151, 174, 138, 186, 128, 136, 179, 163, 152, 131)
y <- c(63, 81, 56, 91, 47, 57, 76, 72, 62, 48)
relation <- lm(y~x) 
print(relation)
beta=solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%(t(x)%*%y)
print(beta)
```

---

Result from `lm` coeff = 0.6746

Result from beta econometrics = 0.4287

Why?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Questions focusing on *programming, debugging, or performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform* are [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Still, what you are doing is basically estimating the same model without the intercept (see yourself `lm(y~x -1)`). Use `model.matrix()` function before solving the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results differ because you didn't include the intercept:

```r
lm(y ~ 0 + x)
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ 0 + x)
## 
## Coefficients:
##      x  
## 0.4287
```

or

```r
X <- cbind(Intercept = 1, x)
solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% (t(X) %*% y)
##                  [,1]
## Intercept -38.4550871
## x           0.6746104
```

This has nothing to do with econometrics and I doubt any econometrics handbook or course recommends not including intercept as [it is a bad practice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model).